# How to call a codeigniter helper function using JQuery AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a function defined in my helper function in codeigniter that returns the formatted price when val and currency id is passed to it.

```
if(!function_exists('format_price')){
function format_price($val,$curency_id=NULL){
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('currency_model');
    if ($curency_id) {
        $Result=$CI->currency_model->getcurrency($curency_id);
        $dec_place=round($Result['decimal_place']);
        $value=number_format((float)$val,$dec_place,'.',',');
        return $Result['symbol_left'].$value ." ".$Result['symbol_right'];
    }
    else{
        $Result=$CI->currency_model->getDefaultCurrency();
        $dec_place=round($Result['decimal_place']);
        $value=number_format((float)$val,$dec_place,'.',',');
        return $Result['symbol_left'].$value ." ".$Result['symbol_right'];
    }
   }
}
```

What I need is to call this function through ajax in javascript code.
is this possible without a controller, or do I have to make a controller?

Comment: You have to call a controller which will call your helper and return the results

Comment: i tried but it does't show the return value .

Comment: Any error ? Test your controller first, make sure it returns something. If it does, then check your ajax call.

Comment: it return but as undefine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a request via controller, then call that function through that controller, something like:

```
$("#id").change(function()
{       
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: base_url + "controller_name/your_function", 
     data: {val: $("#your_val").val(),currency_id: $("#your_cur").val()},
     dataType: "JSON",  
     cache:false,
     success: 
          function(data){
            $("#your_elem").val(data.price);
      }
});
```

Then on your controller:

```
public function yourfunction()
{
   $data = $this->input->post();
   $price = format_price($data['val'],$data['currency_id']);
   echo json_encode(array('price' => $price));
}
```

Comment: when i return data `success:function(){ return data;}` it gives undefined

Comment: You shoud use `data.price`

Answer (score -1):

instead of using ajax try like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    (function(){
      <?php if(helper_function($variable)) { ?>
          now your jquery script..........
      <?php } ?>
    });
  });
</script>
```

customize above code as u want....

Comment: thanks for replay but you are not getting me .
i want to called helper function .

Comment: as per my understanding u want to use the helper function in jquery..so `<?php if(helper_function($variable)) { ?>` will call your helper function...

Comment: my variable is var currency_id,and and var total_amout,and it cannot be passed  like <?php if(helper_function(total_amount,currency_id)) { ?>
because these are jquery variables .

Comment: u can use php and/or jquery for total_amount  and currency_id....before call the helper method......you are trying to break the mvc structure...so you have to do something like this